# "Too many redirects" from webpage made with Namecheap and github hosting

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, github, namecheap

I have set up my first small static webpage using Namecheap and Github for hosting: http://www.keithgardner.me

The webpage has typically loaded fine on Mac computers and iOS devices. I noticed tonight on my Mac running 10.10.3 (the newest Yosemite as of April 15, 2015), the webpage would not load using Safari. It gave me the error "Too many redirects trying to load the page ..."

I did notice on chrome browser on a windows computer the same error occurred. The whole structure of my webpage is open source on github here https://github.com/keithgardner2/keithgardner2.github.io

I would love if someone could give me insight as to what is happening here. All I am using is html and CSS for the styling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a redirect loop- from keithgardner.me to www.keithgardner.me to keithgardner.me to www.keithgardner.me and so on. Can you post any .htaccess or anything that controls this?? You have a code error some place.

Comment: I'm not sure about any .htcaccess. The link to my code is here: https://github.com/keithgardner2/keithgardner2.github.io Could it be either in my index.html or my sitemap.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided (github.com/keithgardner2/keithgardner2.github.io) works fine. However, the domain name keithgardner.me has 3 A records - 2 are github.com and 1 is NameCheap. There has to be something that NameCheap is doing incorrectly. In fact, this is likely far too complicated a set-up for what you are trying to do.

I suggest logging onto your registrar's control panel and deleting your 3 A records. You do not need NameCheap. But take notes anyway just in case you need to drop back!

You can replace your A records with 2 CNAME records.

One would point your domain name keithgardner.me to github.com/keithgardner2/keithgardner2.github.io and the other would point www.keithgardner.me to github.com/keithgardner2/keithgardner2.github.io.

That should be all you need to make this work properly.

Comment: I looked in my name cheap set up. I have 4 entries: The first two are IP entries that are A records. The next is http://www.keithgardner.me/, which is type URL redirect. The last is keithgardner2.github.io. of CName (alias). I think I messed this up.. I'm going to see if I can fix it now

Comment: CNAME is what you want. DNS does not redirect. It only assigns names to IP addresses and names to names (CNAME - alias).

Comment: BTW- I have a boiler problem in my apartment building today... so I am up and down from the basement mostly all day focusing on getting it to work before the weekend where it will get cool again.

Comment: Sorry to hear about your boiler problem, thats pretty random. Anyways, I got it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @keithgardner I am glad it is working for you. I got my boiler to work too. One clogged filter and a senior moment when I forgot about the exterior temperature cutout. It acted like I was out of oil so I bought oil. But that was not it. Could not get it to cycle- too warm outside- just had to adjust the cutout temp, then the filter was clogged. Second one this winter! Being an apartment building, the boiler is huge and requires a lot more care than a home boiler. Oh well. I am set for a while... again... at least till fall... then I get to start all over again. ;-) Nap time!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the solution was for me that in my github CNAME file, I had to change my webpage title. So after I changed it to "www.mywebpage.hu" (before it was without "www."), then no more redirect problems happened. I've checked your CNAME, and you don't have 'www.' too, maybe it will help if you complete your title with this.